# Cast de array al filtrar con stream falla

Tags: java, filtro, stream

Tengo 3 arrays de una clase llamada `TangerMedObject`. Al filtrar con `Arrays.stream` y pasar el resultado a un Array, si intento hacer un cast del array devuelto al tipo `TangerMedObject[]` (que es lo que realmente se devuelve), obtengo un error:

> " java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
> [Les.portel.serviciosportuarios.entity.TangerMedObject;"

Sin embargo, si guardo el array que devuelve el `stream` de java en un `Object[]`, funciona y veo que en el `Object[]` es un array compuesto de objetos `TangerMedObject`.

Falla:

```
// listaCamiones y listaContenedores son variables del tipo TangerMedObject[]
// Dentro de los camiones nos quedamos con los registros que tambien tengan
// contenedores
listaCamiones = (TangerMedObject[]) Arrays.stream(listaCamiones)
                                    .filter(x -> x.getPlateauNo() != null).toArray();

// Dentro de los contenedores nos quedamos con los registros que tambien tengan
// camiones
listaContenedores = (TangerMedObject[]) Arrays.stream(listaContenedores)
                                    .filter(x -> x.getTrackNo() != null).toArray();
                            
// Unimos el resultado en un solo array
listaCompleta = ArrayUtils.addAll(listaCamiones, listaContenedores);
```

Funciona:

```
// Dentro de los camiones nos quedamos con los registros que tambien tengan
// remolque
Object[] camionesTemporal = Arrays.stream(listaCamiones)
                                    .filter(x -> x.getUnitNo() != null).toArray();

// Dentro de los remolques nos quedamos con los registros que tambien tengan
// camiones
Object[] remolquesTemporal = (TangerMedObject[]) Arrays.stream(listaRemolques)
                                    .filter(x -> x.getTrackNo() != null).toArray();
                            
// Unimos el resultado en un solo array
listaCompleta = ArrayUtils.addAll(camionesTemporal, remolquesTemporal);
```

Me gustaría saber si hay manera de guardar el resultado del `stream` en un array del objeto que yo quiero, en lugar de en un `Object[]`.

Comment: cuál es el tipo de listaCamiones y de listaRemolques?

Comment: // listaCamiones y listaContenedores son variables del tipo TangerMedObject[]

Answer (score 0):

Sí hay manera, pasándole el arreglo en el que quieres guardarlo en el proceso antes de regresarlo.

```
// listaCamiones y listaContenedores son variables del tipo TangerMedObject[]
// Dentro de los camiones nos quedamos con los registros que tambien tengan
// contenedores
        listaCamiones = Arrays.stream(listaCamiones)
                .filter(x -> x.getPlateauNo() != null).toArray(TangerMedObject[]::new);

// Dentro de los contenedores nos quedamos con los registros que tambien tengan
// camiones
        listaContenedores = (TangerMedObject[]) Arrays.stream(listaContenedores)
                .filter(x -> x.getTrackNo() != null).toArray(TangerMedObject[]::new);

// Unimos el resultado en un solo array
        listaCompleta = ArrayUtils.addAll(listaCamiones, listaContenedores);
```

lo que ves que dice `::new` es una referencia estática para la creación de un objeto